# When I assign my point collection the page disappear

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I'm programming a tuner, and I wanna create a graphic in my panorama.
However I've an issue, in fact when I assign my point collection all of panorama page is erased.
So how can I solve that ?

My xaml code

```
<controls:PanoramaItem Header="Graphic">     
      <StackPanel>      
         <Canvas Visibility="Visible" Width="530" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Text="|0" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="380"/>
            <TextBlock Text="|50" Canvas.Left="25" Canvas.Top="380"/>
            <TextBlock Text="|100" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="380"/>
            <TextBlock Text="|200" Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="380"/>
            <TextBlock Text="|300" Canvas.Left="150" Canvas.Top="380"/>
            <TextBlock Text="|440" Canvas.Left="220" Canvas.Top="380"/>

            <TextBlock Text="|500" Canvas.Left="250" Canvas.Top="380"/>
            <TextBlock Text="|600" Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Top="380"/>
            <TextBlock Text="|700" Canvas.Left="350" Canvas.Top="380"/>
               <Polygon x:Name="graph"
                    Points="0,150 400,125 400,275 300,200"
                    Stroke="Brown"
                    StrokeThickness="0.4" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
                  <Polygon.Fill>
                      <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.9"/>
                  </Polygon.Fill>
               </Polygon>
            </Canvas>
         </StackPanel>
</controls:PanoramaItem>
```

And my C# code called every 500 ms

```
double[] spectr = FftAlgorithm.Calculate(x);// To have the spectr
myPointCollection.Add(new System.Windows.Point(0, 370));
for(int i = 0; i < spectr.Length;i+= 2)
    {
            myPointCollection.Add(new System.Windows.Point(0+i/2, 370 - spectr[i]/2)); 
            if (i >= 400*1)
            {
                myPointCollection.Add(new System.Windows.Point(0+455/4,370));
                break;
            }
    }


graph.Points = myPointCollection;
```

Thanks in advance !

Edit :
My fft algo :

```
struct ComplexNumber
{
    public double Re;
    public double Im;

    public ComplexNumber(double re)
    {
        this.Re = re;
        this.Im = 0;
    }

    public ComplexNumber(double re, double im)
    {
        this.Re = re;
        this.Im = im;
    }

    public static ComplexNumber operator *(ComplexNumber n1, ComplexNumber n2)
    {
        return new ComplexNumber(n1.Re * n2.Re - n1.Im * n2.Im,
            n1.Im * n2.Re + n1.Re * n2.Im);
    }

    public static ComplexNumber operator +(ComplexNumber n1, ComplexNumber n2)
    {
        return new ComplexNumber(n1.Re + n2.Re, n1.Im + n2.Im);
    }

    public static ComplexNumber operator -(ComplexNumber n1, ComplexNumber n2)
    {
        return new ComplexNumber(n1.Re - n2.Re, n1.Im - n2.Im);
    }

    public static ComplexNumber operator -(ComplexNumber n)
    {
        return new ComplexNumber(-n.Re, -n.Im);
    }

    public static implicit operator ComplexNumber(double n)
    {
        return new ComplexNumber(n, 0);
    }

    public ComplexNumber PoweredE()
    {
        double e = Math.Exp(Re);
        return new ComplexNumber(e * Math.Cos(Im), e * Math.Sin(Im));
    }

    public double Power2()
    {
        return Re * Re - Im * Im;
    }

    public double AbsPower2()
    {
        return Re * Re + Im * Im;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}+i*{1}", Re, Im);
    }
}

public static class FftAlgorithm
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates FFT using Cooley-Tukey FFT algorithm.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x">input data</param>
    /// <returns>spectrogram of the data</returns>
    /// <remarks>
    /// If amount of data items not equal a power of 2, then algorithm
    /// automatically pad with 0s to the lowest amount of power of 2.
    /// </remarks>
    public static double[] Calculate(double[] x)
    {
        int length;
        int bitsInLength;
        if (IsPowerOfTwo(x.Length))
        {
            length = x.Length;
            bitsInLength = Log2(length) - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            bitsInLength = Log2(x.Length);
            length = 1 << bitsInLength;
            // the items will be pad with zeros
        }

        // bit reversal
        ComplexNumber[] data = new ComplexNumber[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            int j = ReverseBits(i, bitsInLength);
            data[j] = new ComplexNumber(x[i]);
        }

        // Cooley-Tukey 
        for (int i = 0; i < bitsInLength; i++)
        {
            int m = 1 << i;
            int n = m * 2;
            double alpha = -(2 * Math.PI / n);

            for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
            {
                // e^(-2*pi/N*k)
                ComplexNumber oddPartMultiplier = new ComplexNumber(0, alpha * k).PoweredE();

                for (int j = k; j < length; j += n)
                {
                    ComplexNumber evenPart = data[j];
                    ComplexNumber oddPart = oddPartMultiplier * data[j + m];
                    data[j] = evenPart + oddPart;
                    data[j + m] = evenPart - oddPart;
                }
            }
        }

        // calculate spectrogram
        double[] spectrogram = new double[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < spectrogram.Length; i++)
        {

                spectrogram[i] = data[i].AbsPower2();

        }
        return spectrogram;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets number of significat bytes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="n">Number</param>
    /// <returns>Amount of minimal bits to store the number.</returns>
    private static int Log2(int n)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (n > 0)
        {
            ++i; n >>= 1;
        }
        return i;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reverses bits in the number.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="n">Number</param>
    /// <param name="bitsCount">Significant bits in the number.</param>
    /// <returns>Reversed binary number.</returns>
    private static int ReverseBits(int n, int bitsCount)
    {
        int reversed = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < bitsCount; i++)
        {
            int nextBit = n & 1;
            n >>= 1;

            reversed <<= 1;
            reversed |= nextBit;
        }
        return reversed;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if number is power of 2.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="n">number</param>
    /// <returns>true if n=2^k and k is positive integer</returns>
    private static bool IsPowerOfTwo(int n)
    {
        return n > 1 && (n & (n - 1)) == 0;
    }
}
```

Exemple of valor returned bu this alogorithm (divised by 2 here as in my point collection) :

```
Array
7774,84102428705
3,77541922071645
2,60171097464947
4,25540621691683
5,28851887723449
3,4148780139543
2,76973970084357
1,99548270720925
2,48089729433758
1,81148493997232
4,08591050588941
3,86634237956173
2,23154042032444
2,34943177165949
0,202241877529014
0,361856279722826
0,305770091815949
1,10819055376782
1,14078528143499
0,0885925819196023
0,0589821600576737
1,82627322162955
0,510590967254011
1,09703702271706
0,624027733620266
1,38613991581386
0,61563282026637
0,833719920552669
1,72066078720428
0,61866640580564
0,311134872285707
0,545134957482531
1,32248892387885
0,280664970077368
0,288037724854005
0,478421643868339
0,0965479866862064
2,77251684855075
4,28321499123499
0,498259034734298
9,93132231440244
2,10269510682998
0,805331883010264
```

Comment: Could you show how FftAlgorithm returns a double array?

Comment: Yes of course, I've edited my first post.

Comment: 7774,84102428705 should be 7774.84102428705 to be double, anyway i think that 7774,84102428705 is too big for your view so you should calculate everything based on the bounds of the view

Comment: What is the value of x when it is passed to Calculate Method?

Comment: X is from my microphone buffer : microphone.GetData(buffer);


            double[] x = new double[buffer.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
            {
                x[i] = buffer[i] / (32768.0);
            }
Anyway I've solve the problem, whith deleting 7774,84102428705 number, so my graphic begin at 10, and no problem he is drawing fine.

Comment: but does 7774,...... comes from the microphone?

Comment: Yes it comes from the microphone, it's very strange.

Comment: Maybe it is the peek of the turning on of the microphone. Try to skip the first second or less